# SwuifUI transitions for parameterized list

Tags: list, swiftui, transition

In learning SwiftUI I'm trying to do transition animations I used with UIKit. I sometimes used pages with tables that changed with a parameter by using a containerView and transitioning between children. The SwiftUI equivalent seems to be a single List View dependent on the parameter. But it seems that .transitions don't work well since no view is being removed/inserted in the hierarchy (and simple animations don't give me the transition options I want). The only way I have made it work at all is by "manually" removing the old List and inserting the new one, but that seems a kludge and didn't work perfectly. Here's a toy version of the code that illustrated the problem -- the inserted green rectangle is just for comparison -- the transition works fine for it but not for the List.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let listItems:[[String]] = [["A0","B0"],["A1","B1"]]
    @State var pointer:Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           List(listItems[pointer], id:\.self)
            {item in Text(item)
                .foregroundColor(self.pointer == 0 ? Color.blue : Color.purple)
            }
            .transition(.offset(x: -600, y: 0))

            if pointer == 1 {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .transition(.offset(x: 500, y: 300))
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)){
            self.pointer = (self.pointer + 1) % 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've found a partial solution, but it behaves strangely. Instead of a single List with varying content, transitions seem to require separate lists which are inserted/removed. Here is a simple implementation

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let listItems:[[String]] = [["A0","B0"],["A1","B1"],["A2","B2"]]
    @State var pointer:Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{ForEach(0...2, id: \.self)
            {index in
                ZStack{
                    if index == self.pointer {
                    List(self.listItems[index], id:\.self)
                       {item in HStack{Text(item);Spacer()}
                            .foregroundColor(self.pointer == 0 ? Color.blue : Color.purple)
                            .frame(height:20)
                            .padding(2)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                        }
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .offset(x: 400, y: -370), removal: .offset(x: 0, y: -870)))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)){
            self.pointer = (self.pointer + 1) % 3
            }
        }
```

But it responds oddly to choice of offsets -- I don't understand the -370 y-offset needed to make insertions come in horizontally -- it was found by trial/error. And the transition 2->0 is different from the other two.

Comment: It is true, as you mentioned, that transition works only when view is inserted or removed, so it is not clear what do you want to see by applying transition to persistent List.

Comment: Well, I want the list with one set of items to be removed and the list with a new set to replace it. With UIKit I could do that in lots of interesting ways such as splitting the old one down the middle and sliding the halves to each side to reveal the new one which had been inserted underneath the old one.